# Windows 10 20H1 2004 sidebar (Notifications, Wifi networks, ...) not showing up

Tags: windows, windows-10, wifi-configuration, notification-area

I did a fresh install of Windows 10 To Go. In the oobe (is it still called by this name?) I skipped to connect to a Network. After enabling Bitlocker I wanted to connect to a Wifi, but If I click the corresponding option (tray icon or network adapter options) the sidebar that displays the Networks is not shown. I noticed there is a unread notification indicated by the number next to the notification icon in the task bar and clicking on it does not show the notifications. I assume technically both sidebar-version use the same API that is for some reason dysfunctional ATM. Does someone now a fix for this? I tried some "Windows Sidebar re-installations", but this seems to be different that the old Vista Windows Sidebar.

I currently try to install non-essential drivers and Windows updates.

PS: It is awesome that guest posting is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Windows to Go is no longer supported starting in Windows 10 V2004

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview#:~:text=Windows To Go is a,USB-connected external drive on PCs.

> Windows To Go is removed in Windows 10, version 2004 and later
>   operating systems. The feature does not support feature updates and
>   therefore does not enable you to stay current. It also requires a
>   specific type of USB that is no longer supported by many OEMs.

Comment: Seriously? Microsoft can be that damn annoying!

Comment: @JohnMeyer - Microsoft announced the discontinuation of Windows to Go over 2 years ago.